# Given an array of NSDictionary object how to get all the keys?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

If you have an array of dictionaries, how do I create a new array containing all the keys present for each dictionary in the array ?

```
NSArray *array = @[@{@"key1" : @"value 1"},
                   @{@"key2" : @"value 2"},
                   @{@"key3" : @"value 3"} ];

// how to achieve this?
NSArray *allKeys = @{@"key1", @"key2", @"key3"};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

plz use this code, I think it helps you

```
 NSArray *array = @[@{@"key1" : @"value 1"},
                       @{@"key2" : @"value 2"},
                       @{@"key3" : @"value 3"} ];

    NSMutableArray *key_array=[NSMutableArray array];

    for (NSDictionary *dictionary in array) {

        NSArray *key_dictionary=[dictionary allKeys];

        for (NSString *string_key in key_dictionary) {
            [key_array addObject:string_key];
        }

    }
    NSLog(@"%@",key_array);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you know that each element in the array is an `NSDictionary`, you can call the `allKeys` method on each item in the array.  I've added a type check to this example in case your array contains other objects that are not `NSDictionary`:

```
NSArray *array = @[@{@"key1" : @"value 1"},
                   @{@"key2" : @"value 2"},
                   @{@"key3" : @"value 3"}];

NSMutableArray *allKeys = [@[] mutableCopy];

for (id obj in array) {
    if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
        NSDictionary *dict = obj;
        [allKeys addObjectsFromArray:[dict allKeys]];
    }
}

NSLog(@"%@", allKeys);
```

Logs:

```
2016-04-20 11:38:42.096 ObjC-Workspace[10684:728578] (
    key1,
    key2,
    key3
)
```

And if you need an immutable `NSArray` instead of an `NSMutableArray`:

```
NSArray *allKeysImmutable = [allKeys copy];
```

Comment: If you know all elements in the array are dictionaries, change the `for` to `for (NSDictionary *dict in array)`. and get rid of the `isKindOfClass` check.

Comment: @rmaddy Yep, that's what I had in my first edit but changed for safety, since SO is prone to copy-paste coders.  Edited my answer to explain this.  Thank you.

Comment: Why creating a copy of an empty immutable array instead of just creating an empty mutable array directly?

Comment: @Sulthan is there a performance difference between `[@[] mutableCopy]`, `[NSMutableArray array]`, or `[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]`?  I just used the array literal syntax as shorthand (although it isn't much shorter or clearer than `[NSMutableArray array]`).

Comment: @JAL I am not sure whether there is a performance difference, it wouldn't be significant anyway. I was just wondering.

Answer (score 1):

Although Objective-C lacks an array-flattening method, you can nevertheless simplify the outer step:

```
NSMutableArray *result = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for(NSArray *keys in [array valueForKey:@"allKeys"])
    [result addObjectsFromArray:keys];

return [result copy];
```

Or, if you need keys deduplicated:

```
NSMutableSet *result = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];

for(NSArray *keys in [array valueForKey:@"allKeys"])
    [result unionSet:[NSSet setWithArray:keys]];

return [result allObjects];
```

... the only type assumption being (only slightly looser than) that `array` is all dictionaries. If you can annotate the collections any further then I recommend that you do.